# Google Drive Api in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-drive-api

I am facing some difficulties in apply the google drive api to my angular web app. I tried copying the code from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js to my components html but I keep getting an error that says

`zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught {error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhos…itelist this origin for your project's client ID."}`

However, when I put it as a normal index.html without it being in an angular app, the client id is valid. Is it possible that it is because of how angular renders the components, resulting in 'async defer' to be not working? If so, how do I resolve this.

I tried using @types/gapi and gapi-auth2 but I also encounter errors that the module cannot be found. I did many fixes like adding the compilerType but it still does not work so I am trying to use the default html. Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to get google drive integrated in your angular app? if yes, can you elaborate?